# I cant add item after I use my pop() function in my Linked List

Tags: c

Why the program doesn't add after pops the last item? There is something missing with pointers on these 2 functions

First, I have defined a Node struct and named it `node`. Then created 2 pointers to point the first and the last one.

```
typedef struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
} node;


node* first = NULL, * last = NULL;
```

Here, Pop function. I have created a walk pointer. If the first node is going to be deleted, first will be pointed to NULL. Else, it will iterate to the last node and deallocates it.

```
void Pop() {

    if (first == NULL) {
        printf("\n\nLIST IS EMPTY\n\n");
    }
    else if (first->next == NULL) {
        node* temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));

        temp = first;
        free(temp);
        first = NULL;
    }
    else {
        node* walk = first;

        while (walk->next->next != NULL) {
            walk = walk->next;
        }

        free(walk->next);

        walk->next = NULL;

    }

}
```

Push function will create a node and add it to the list. If the list is empty, it will be pointed out by `first` and `last`, else it will be connected to the last node then it will become the `last` node.

```
void Push(int data) {
    node* temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));

    temp->data = data;

    if (first == NULL) {
        first = temp;
        temp->next = NULL;
        last = first;
    }
    else {
        last->next = temp;
        last = last->next;
        last->next = NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why can't you add more items?  What happens when you try?  What sequence of inputs did you provide that led up to the problem?

Comment: Can you add the code for the Push() function to the question?

Comment: @ScottHunter first, I use my push function. I input 1, 2, 3 ,4 ,5 in order and I can see the list with Display, but after I use pop, I just cant add again. It just doesnt add new items.

Comment: Can you `Display` after `Pop`?

Comment: @jmq Here you go, first I thought I was losing the first pointer of the list. But I couldn't figure it out completely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Pop() you never update last, so it still points to the deleted node.  When you push again you are linking the deleted node to the new node.

```
void Pop() {
    node* walk = first;
    node* deleted = NULL;

    while (walk->next->next != NULL) {
        walk = walk->next;
    }

    deleted = walk->next;
    free(deleted);
    walk->next = NULL;
    last = walk;  // <-- add this
}
```

Also, Pop() will fail (and probably crash) if you only have one node in the list because walk->next->next will dereference a NULL pointer.